# Работа с localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Ребята, подскажите как хранить записи в таблице в localStarage, что бы после загрузки все осталось на своих местах. Я  попыталась, но что-то пошло не так. может таблицы не хранятся в localStarage, а нужно брать артиллерию по тяжелей - JSON?подскажите

```js
//localStorage для таблицы 
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("saveTable");
//localStorage для input
document.getElementById("fild").value = localStorage.getItem("name");
var fild = document.getElementById('fild');
localStorage.setItem('name', 'fild');

var counter = 1;
var table = document.querySelector('.table tbody');
var valueTab = buttonClick.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var t = document.getElementById('t');

  var row = t.insertRow();
 //localStorage для таблицы 
localStorage.setItem('saveTable', 'valueTab');
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName = 'button') {
    row.insertCell().innerHTML = counter;
    counter++;
  }
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = fild.value;

  row.insertCell().innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="DELETE" class="del"  />';

  var del = document.getElementsByClassName('del');
  for (var i = 0; i < del.length; i++) {
    del[i].addEventListener('click', function(but) {
      var trq = this.parentNode.parentNode;
      trq.remove();
    });
  }

  fild.value = "";

})
```

```css
#fild {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#firstLine {
  text-align: center;
}

tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#buttonClick {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Name of employer</p>
<input type="text" id="fild"><br>
<button id="buttonClick">Result</button>
<div id="table">
  <table id="t">
    <tr id="firstLine">
      <td>№</td>
      <td>Name of employer</td>
      <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Лучше юзать `localStorage['name'] = 'value';` - это работает быстрее. И получается, что у вас одно и тоже значение перезаписывается, после обновления скрипта.

Comment: @And, это работает быстрее чем что?

Comment: @Grundy, чем `localStorage.setItem` и `localStorage.getItem`

Comment: @And, ты не прав - это одна и та же функция

Comment: @Grundy, несогласен. Во первых не требуется дергать функцию, а во вторых в функции еще до кучи есть проверки и условия, нежели дернуть массив.

Comment: @And, есть доказательства?

Comment: @And, то, что интерфейс выглядит как простой объект, не значит, что это простой объект. Даже в самой спецификации нет различий между записями `value = storage . getItem ( key )` и 
`value = storage[key]`

Comment: @Grundy, да, что ты говоришь - `set+get: 1.582275390625ms`
`array: 0.10498046875ms` - затести у себя. И убедишься.

Comment: @And, без кода тестов цифры ничего не значат. а так же как минимум версии браузера

Answer (score 1):

Во первых в `localStorage` хранятся только строки.

Вот таким `localStorage['name'] = 'fild';` образом вы записали строку `fild` в ячейку `name`, не нужно использовать кавычки, если хотите сохранить значение переменной `fild`.

Далее, в `var fild = document.getElementById('fild');` вы пытаетесь сохранить HTML элемент? Это тоже не получится, но я так понимаю вам нужно только значение этого поля, так что можете сохранить значение так `localStorage['name'] = fild.value;`

Если вы хотите сохранить `JS` объект с полями например такой

```
var obj = {name: 'str', num:0};
```

то для его сохранения вам понадобится перевести его в `JSON` строку

```
localStorage['savedObj'] = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

а при его чтении распарсить его

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage['savedObj']);
```

Comment: я бы посоветовал пользоваться setItem и getItem, а не использовать localStorage как объект. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: @Komdosh, спасибо за очень подробное описание! но `localStorage['name'] = fild.value;` не дало никаких результатов. потом я написала такой код `var fild = document.getElementById('fild');
if( fild.value !== '') {
  fild.value = localStorage.getItem("name")
 } localStorage.setItem("name", fild)` но он тоже не заработал. в значение value [object HTMLInputElement]. что не так. подскажите. я немножко не догоняю))

Comment: ну какое-то странное условие, если оно не пустое, загрузить знечение. `[object HTMLInputElement]` означает, что как раз таки был сохранён DOM объект, а не его значение

Comment: @Komdosh, окей, как сохранить его значение?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086959/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-textarea-%d0%b8-localstorge