# Как правильно соединять textArea и localStorge?

Tags: javascript, scheduler

Нужно создать простой список дел html, чтобы он мог редактировать события. Хранить события будет в локальном хранилище. Пока на руках имею следующее.
Проблема не могу сохраниться (saving0). Вообще говоря, хорошо бы найти готовое решение, но я пока не нашел.Все!!!

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="T1"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="save" onclick=saving0()/><input>

<script>
  var Key1 = "Areg";
  var Key2 = 1234567;
  var Key3 = "Arthur";
  //localStorage["1"] = Key1;
  //localStorage["2"] = Key2;
  //localStorage["3"] = Key3;
  var U = localStorage["1"];

  function saving0() {

    localStorage["1"] = (getText0());

  }

  function getText0() {
    str1 = document.getElementById('T1');
    return (str1.value + "");
  }

  function setText0(value) {
    document.getElementById('T1').value = value;
  }
</script>
<script>
  setText0(localstorage["1"]);
  //setText0(getText0());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="T1"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="save" onclick="saving0()" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script>
//После первого запуска можно отключить (закоментировать) 2,3,4 строки кода, чтобы удостовериться, что все сохраняется в локальном хранилище
localStorage["Key1"]="Value1";
//localStorage["Key2"]="Value2";
localStorage["Key3"]="Value3";
var U = localStorage["Key2"];
function saving0() {
  localStorage["Key2"] = (getText0());
}
function getText0() {
  str1 = document.getElementById('T1');
  return (str1.value + "");
}
function setText0(value) {
  document.getElementById('T1').value = value;
}
setText0(U)
</script>

</style>
</html>
```

Comment: что за цыганские фокусы?))

Answer (score 1):

```js
var U = localStorage["1"];

function saving0() {
  localStorage["1"] = (getText0());
}

function getText0() {
  str1 = document.getElementById('T1');
  return (str1.value + "");
}

function setText0(value) {
  document.getElementById('T1').value = value;
}

setText0(U);
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="T1"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="save" onclick="saving0()" />
```

Comment: Работает на сайте с ошибками, но у меня в браузере без ошибок.